# Python: Loop with list, use list value in directory

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop

Newbie in python, I have the following code:

```
XX = [A,B,C,D,E]
src_path = 'C:\love\hi_XX\you'

for file in src_path:
    Do something....
```

I want to loop through all files in `C:\love\hi_A\you` first, then `C:\love\hi_B\you` all the way to `C:\love\hi_E\you`.

I am using Spyder. How do I make this work? Thank you.

Comment: what are you looking for? to read or write to file?

Comment: Looking for a way help to use for loop through all folders without repeat the 5 times for loop

Comment: Awesome. Thank you AJNeufeld

Answer (score 2):

You can create the src_path that you want by using a for loop against the elements in XX

```
for X in XX:
    src_path = r'C:\love\hi_' +X + r'\you'
```

Then, within that loop, you can use `os.walk` like in the other answer

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Got error said A, B C... undefind name. Then I pgot error can't assign to literalut A= 'A', B = 'B'

Comment: are you trying to say you can't enter the command    
    A='A' ?

Comment: Got the solution from AJNewfeld

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for that in the standard "os" module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Read through, but not applied in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your literals in your array.  And `os.path.join` is a always a good idea for joining together path components:

```
import os.path
XX = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
for X in XX:
    src_path = os.path.join(r'C:\love', "hi_"+X, "you")
    print(src_path)
```

> C:\love\hi_A\you
>   C:\love\hi_B\you
>   C:\love\hi_C\you
>   C:\love\hi_D\you
>   C:\love\hi_E\you

Finally, if `C:\love\hi_XX\you` are directories, and you need files beneath them, then use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) on your `src_path` values.